# Jinja2 Namespaces odd result

Tags: ansible, namespaces, jinja2

Im trying to set a global variable within a jinja2 template so i can set variables inside and outside of a loop. I've used this before and its worked but in this case it doesnt and i'm struggling to find out why.

This is my j2 template.

```
{% set found = namespace() %}
{% set vrf = namespace() %}
{% for group_item in site_master_list -%}
{%     for host_item in site.list -%}
{%         if group_item.ip_addr != host_item.ip_addr %}
none match {{ group_item.ip_addr }} none match {{ host_item.ip_addr }} 
{%            set found.tracker = false %}
does it have vrf {{ host_item.vrf }}
{%            if host_item.vrf != "" %}
{%                set vrf = namespace(id=host_item.vrf) %}
vrf {{ vrf }}
vrf.id {{ vrf.id }}
{%            endif %}
{%         endif %}
{%     endfor %}
bottom vrf {{ vrf }}
{%- endfor %}
```

This is the output

```
bottom vrf <Namespace {}>none match 10.180.193.235 none match 10.112.208.11 
does it have vrf management
vrf <Namespace {'id': 'management'}>
vrf.id management
bottom vrf <Namespace {}>
```

As you can see i'm setting host_item.vrf to the namespace vrf so i can use vrf.id outside of the loop further down the template.

Where i've got *bottom vrf {{ vrf }}* you can see in the output the empty namespace where it shows

**bottom vrf <namespace {}>**

Returning vrf.id within the loop returns **management** the correct value and all is good.

Anyone got any suggestions why i cant return vrf.id outside of the inner loop? I was returning vrf.id but Ansible returns the below which is correct because 'id' doesn't exist at that stage in the template.

*''jinja2.utils.Namespace object'' has no attribute ''id'''*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by replacing

```
{%                set vrf = namespace(id=host_item.vrf) %}
```

With

```
{%                set vrf.value = host_item.vrf %}
```

Not sure why this worked previously but the latter works.